# Verify that ion-checkbox is checked in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a checkbox list, I need to identify when at least 1 of these items is checked to enable a button.

So far I've managed to do that, but it doesn't work with `event.target.checked`, just nothing happens, I also just tried `event.checked` and nothing.

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let option of question.options">
      <ion-label>{{option}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox color="secondary" value="option" (click)="isChecked($event)" name="option"></ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

file.ts:

```
isChecked(event) {
  if ( event.target.checked ) {
    console.log("Checked!");
    this.btnDisabled = false;
 }
}
```

Ionic version: 3.9.5

Angular 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-radio-g14dnm?embed=1&file=app/app.html)**

Template:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let option of question.options">
      <ion-label>{{option}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox color="secondary" value="option" (click)="onChange(option)" name="option"></ion-checkbox>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<button [disabled]="checkedItems.length <1 ">Save </button>
```

TS:

```
 checkedItems = []


 onChange(item) {
    if(this.checkedItems.includes(item)) {
      this.checkedItems = this.checkedItems.filter((value)=>value!=item);

    } else {
      this.checkedItems.push(item)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great! It worked! I just had to exchange `includes (item)` for `.indexOf(item) !== -1`. 
Thank you!

Comment: Ya.. `indexOf(item) !== -1` is better. You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Use **`ionChange`** instead **`click`** and **`event.checked`** instead **`event.target.checked`**.

```
<ion-checkbox color="secondary" value="option" (ionChange)="isChecked($event)" name="option"></ion-checkbox>

isChecked(event) {
  if ( event.checked ) {
    this.btnDisabled = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: It worked! I just can't identify when none of the checkboxes are checked. Any idea?

Comment: you can keep count of checked checkboxes. if it is 0 disable the button.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add an answer after messing around with this for a while. I'm on @ionic/angular@6.0.3.

At some point, the output of $event seems to have changed to include a "detail" property that wasn't mentioned in other answers about working with ion-checkbox.

```js
component.html

<ion-item>
  <ion-checkbox name="agree" value="agree" (ionChange)="onCheck($event)">
  </ion-checkbox>
  <ion-text>I'm agreeing to something</ion-text>
</ion-item>

component.ts

onCheck(event: any) {
  if(event.detail.checked) {
    console.log(`It's checked`, event);
  } else if (!event.detail.checked) {
    console.log(`It's unchecked`, event);
  }
}
```